# How do I add an index to my localstorage using only HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, indexing

This is the HTML for the page used to add a student

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="function.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
    <nav>
        <img src="logo.jpg"><h1 id="titt">North Park Clubs</h1>
    <li><a href="attendance.html">Attendance</a></li>
    </nav>
</header> 
<body>
<h1>Add A Student</h1>
    <input type="text" id="indx"></input>
    <input type="text" id="sFirstName"></input>
    <input type="text" id="sLastName"></input>
    <input type="text" id="sNumber"></input>
    <input type="text" id="sPoints"></input>
    <input type="button" onclick="save()" value="Save"></input>
</body>
```

This is the HTML for the page to view attendance

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script href="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
    <nav>
        <img src="logo.jpg"><h1 id="titt">North Park Clubs</h1>
    <li><a href="attendance.html">Attendance</a></li>
    </nav>
</header>   
<body onload="load()">
<table id="attendance">
    <input type="button" value="Add Student" id="add" link="addStudent.html">

       <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>  
    <td>Student Number</td>
    <td>Points</td>
           <td>Absent (If student is present leave this unchecked)</td>
        </tr>
    <td id="indx"></td>
    <td id="sFirstName"></td>
    <td id="sLastName"></td>
    <td id="sNumber"></td>
    <td id="sPoints"></td>
    <td><input id="a" type="checkbox"></td>
       </table>
</body>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
var indx = [];
var sFirstName = [];
var sLastName = [];
var sNumber = [];
var sPoints = [];
var a = [];
var attendance = [];
var obj = JSON.parse(attendance);
function save(){
    localStorage.setItem("idex", document.getElementById('indx').value);
    localStorage.setItem("fName", document.getElementById('sFirstName').value);
    localStorage.setItem("lName", document.getElementById('sLastName').value);
    localStorage.setItem("numb", document.getElementById('sNumber').value);
}

if (localStorage.clickcount) {
    localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
} else {
    localStorage.clickcount = 1;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " +
localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
//var fName = localStorage.sFirstName;
//var lName = localStorage.sLastName
//var numb = localStorage,sNumber

//onload document.getElementById('attendance');

function load(){
    document.getElementById.idex;
    document.getElementById.fName;
    document.getElementById.lName;
    document.getElementById.numb;
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong so an explanation would also be great! Thanks! :)

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Welcome to the stack overflow. Your question contains too many code. You title is good, but we cannot understand what you are exactly trying to do. Please try to post only related with the question code.

Comment: Why not use localstorage to store an array of objects instead of doing "setItem"    Why not create an object called:  *Entry* and then `var list  = GetItem("data").push(Entry); SetItem("Data", list);`   or better yet:   `localStorage.setItem("data", localStorage.getItem("data").push(new Entry(i,f,l,num));`

Comment: As far as I can see in the  function load() your syntax is wrong, It should be document.getElementById("ID")  -  but even if you correct that it won't do anything since the dom locations are not assigned to any variables or the values stored anywhere. I guess if you could post a more specific question and explain what's going on with the code I would love to help.

Comment: Romain braun The question isHow do I add an index to my localstorage using only HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

> The question is how do I add an index to my localstorage using only HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Coding wise HTML5 and CSS have nothing to do with it except for displaying the end values.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f3aej450/2/

JavaScript(onload):

```
 //check to see if index exists.
// set it to 0 if it does not, 
// otherwise add 1
(localStorage.getItem("index")) ?
localStorage.setItem("index", parseInt(localStorage.getItem('index')) + 1) :
localStorage.setItem("index", 0);

// alert the user to the index number
alert(localStorage.getItem("index"));
```

As a side note, I would suggest using `sessionStorage` as opposed to `localStorage` - the difference is that sessionStorage clears when the browser window/tab is closed. localStorage just sits there until you overwrite it or remove it.